# Can list of directories be parsed into a find command?

Tags: bash, find, zip, for

Suppose I want to unzip files recursively that have the pattern `${file}*.zip` in some directory `/home/A/XML` using `find` command

```
find /home/A/XML -type f -name "${file}*.zip" -exec unzip '{}' -d /target/path \;
```

For now, I wish to parse **a list of directories** instead of just `/home/A/XML`

```
for dir in "${path}"; do        

    find "${dir}" -name "${file}*\.zip" -type f -exec unzip '{}' -d "${dir}"/"${file}" \;

done
```

I tries using a `for` loop to parse the directories but the unzip stop right after the 1st directories, meaning it done the same thing as the previous code, it only unzipped in the directory `/home/A/XML`.

```
caution:  not extracting; -d ignored
```

I got the error above for the remaining directories.
Can anyone please guide me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that list of directories is stored newline-delimited (one on each line) in a scalar variable `$path` (not a good name for a variable as it's special in several shells, though not `bash`), you'd do:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline
set -o noglob # disable glob

for dir in $path # invoke the split+glob operator ($path unquoted)
do
  find "$dir" -name "$file*.zip" -type f -exec unzip -d "$dir/$file" {} \;
done
```

If `$path` was a `bash` array instead as in `path=(dir1 dir2...)`, change the loop to

```
for dir in "${path[@]}"
```

If using GNU `find`, you may want to add a `-quit` predicate at the end or your `find` command to allow only one successful `unzip` per directory unless you want all the `zip` files to be merged into the same directory.

Note that options should be placed before non-option arguments.